# Разъяснение программы на Fortran

Tags: fortran

Здравствуйте. Кому не сложно разъясните пожалуйста построчно данную программу.

Решать ничего не нужно,просто объяснить построчно.

```
Program task1
      real MaxX, MinX, SrX, SrY, SX, SY 
      real Sj, SrU, pol, otr, lol 
      integer nMaxX, nMinX
      dimension X(200),Q(200)
      pi=3.142857142857143
      N=101
      a=0
      b=1
      j=1
      k=1
      m=1
      l=1
!задать      print*, 'a и b-начало и конец отрезка'
!задать      print*, 'N-количество точек'
!задать      print*, 'Введите a,b,N'
!задать      read*, a,b,N
      h=(b-a)/(N-1)
      do i=1,n
      X(i)=a+(i-1)*h
      Q(i)=f(X(i))

      enddo
      MaxX=Q(1)
      MinX=Q(1)
      nMaxX=1
      nMinX=1
      do i=2,n
      if(Q(i) .gt. MaxX) then
      MaxX=Q(i)
      nMaxX=i
      endif
      if(Q(i) .lt. MinX) then
      MinX=Q(i)
      nMinX=i
      endif
      enddo
      print*, 'Максимальное значение:', MaxX
      print*, 'Номер Max элемента:', nMaxX
      print*, 'Минимальное значение:', MinX
      print*, 'Номер Min элемента:', nMinX
      SrY=0
      SY=0
      do i=1,n
      SrY=SrY+Q(i)
      SY=SY+(Q(i)*Q(i))
      enddo
      SrX=SrY/N
      SX=SY/(N)
      lol=sqrt(SX)
      print*, 'Среднее значение функции:', SrX
      print*, 'Средний квадрат функции:', SX
      print*, 'Среднеквадр значение', lol
      pol=0
      otr=0
      do i=1,n
      if(Q(i) .gt. 0) then
      pol=(pol+1)
      endif
      if(Q(i) .lt. 0) then
      otr=(otr+1)
      endif
      enddo
      pol=abs(pol/n-1)
      otr=abs(otr/n-1)
      print*, 'Относ число полож значений:', pol
      print*, 'Относ число отриц значений:', otr
      Sj=0
      do i=1,n
      Sj=Sj+((Q(i)-SrX)**2)
      enddo
      Sj=Sj/N
      Sj=sqrt(Sj)
      print*, 'Среднеквадратич отклонение', Sj
      end

      real function f(x)
      f=x*(1-x)-0.125!test
      !f=((1-x)**j)*(cosh(x)**k)*(x**m)-(x**l)!11var(31net)
      return
      end
```

Comment: именно каждую строку? Неужели строки вида `Sj=0` не понятны? Но если Вы думаете, что когда Вам распишут каждую строку, Вы поймете, что делает вся программа... ошибаетесь.

Возьмите лучше книгу по фортрану.

Comment: Круто. А где если не секрет пишут на фортране?

Comment: В мифи.. :D

Comment: а на каком бы языке программирования было бы понятнее?

Comment: Не понял вашего вопроса :(

Comment: @Александр Котов, оказалось, что в Фортране (по крайней мере gfortran) не различаются большие и маленькие буковки.

Думаю, что теперь программа станет понятней.

Вот что делает это цикл?

      h=(b-a)/(N-1)
      do i=1,n
      X(i)=a+(i-1)*h
      Q(i)=f(X(i))
      enddo

Надеюсь, очевидно, заполняет массивы N значениями в интервале от `a` до `b` с шагом `h`.

Comment: @Александр Котов может быть, если программа была написана на с или пхп, то она была бы понятнее.

Comment: @Александр Котов Вам что-то конкретное непонятно, или Вы хотите, чтобы кто-то выполнил работу по дописыванию комментариев к каждой строке кода? И, разумеется, бесплатно.

Comment: pi=3.142857142857143 ???
Во времена моей молодости число ПИ выглядело несколько иначе. Неужто с тех пор наука шагнула вперед, а я так отстал?

Comment: @alexlz хочу,чтобы кто-то выполнил работу по дописыванию комментов к каждой строчке (почти к каждой) могу и заплатить) в разумных пределах. :)

Comment: Ох, ну и поперло же кому-то. @alexlz, ловите птицу счастья! "То-то денег у него, то-то денег..."

Только что заметил, что ПИ у нас теперь к тому же дробь периодическая. Александр Котов, ну зачем Вам программирование? Денег - полно. Я был бы таким богатым, забросил бы клавиатуру за горионт и жил бы в Сочи. А программируют пусть те, кто победнее.

Comment: @BuilderC настораживает ограничение "в разумных пределах". У нас могут быть разные представления о разумности.

Comment: хоспаде, как приятно вспомнить юные студенческие годы.. ЕС-1036, фортран, девяностые.. пошел смывать скупую мужскую слезу коньяком..

Comment: @BuilderC Этот фортран мне совсем не нужен) меня попросили помочь поискать. Знакомый подсказал данный форум. Вот собственно и задал вопрос тут) я же все-таки больше по web'y специализируюсь :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходник fortran v. >= 77 (не уверен)

Происходит следующее:

1. Объявляем тучу разных переменных включая массивы размерности 200
2. Далее задаемся отрезком `a`, `b` который делим на `N` частей - вводит пользователь
3. Вычисляем на этом отрезке значения функции `f(x)` и складываем их значения в массив
4. Далее пробегаемся по массиву и вычисляем стат. параметры: мин/макс, типа мат.ожидание, средний квадрат и проч.
5. `f(x)` задан в 2-x ипостасях (1 вариант закомментирован): квадратичная парабола и сложная смесь гиперболического косинуса со степенями.

P.S. Как писали в каментах число PI задано неверно. Обычно, число PI в фортране народ задавал как `acos(0.0)`, далее не очень понятно почему взят за основу тип `REAL` надо бы добавить модификатор `DOUBLE PRECISION`

Comment: Благодарю.

Comment: @Barmaley я уже тоже не очень-то помню, но насколько я понял гугла do...enddo -- это уже f77+ (many compilers allow...)

Comment: Ну Fortran-77 как раз и был таким водоразделом, когда были введены все эти нормальные циклы без меток и проч. анахронизмов оставшихся от перфокарт

Comment: @Barmaley ну я ведь ни разу не ветеринар, можно поаккуратней? На странице http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001.html я никакого end do не нашёл (end if там есть). Может я не там искал?

Comment: @alexlz - ну я значит слишком ветеринар и все забыл...

Comment: @Barmaley Бармалей -- не Айболит, Бармалей -- друг Айболита.